# Access data passed to ejs view and manipulate dom

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

When passing data to my ejs view i cannot manipulate the dom using the data.
when trying to use "inline" code nothing happens, and when trying to use script tag i get an error that the data is not defined.

```js
    function per(data){
        data[1].forEach(el=>{
            document.getElementById(el).checked=true
            
        })
    }
```

Comment: As the duplicate suggests, you have client-side code that's supposed to run in the browser and are trying to run it while the template engine processes the template (at which point there's no `document` yet) If you do insert it as `<script>` it'll work in theory, however `data` no longer exists. I assume `data` is a variable passed to `res.render()`? Can you show the ejs loop that uses it? Also, why not simply put the `checked` attribute directly into your template's loop?

Comment: Like this for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-snowflake-eqlzp?file=/src/html/index.ejs (I also recommend using pug over ejs, it's vastly superior and more readable imo)